# Why g++4.9 tries to compile excess code?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, g++4.9

I tried to compile my old code (json to struct parser) that use many template magic (mostly tuples), to give me possibility to describe parser commands like this:

```
auto mesh_parser = TupleParser<Mesh&>::create("Mesh list parser");
mesh_parser >> Ops::read("name") >> Ops::cast(&stringNotEmpty) >> Ops::write(&Mesh::name);
mesh_parser >> Ops::read("file") >> Ops::cast(&stringNotEmpty) >> Ops::write(&Mesh::file);
mesh_parser >> Ops::optional() >> Ops::read("submeshes") >> Ops::unlist() >> Ops::cast(&stringNotEmpty) >> Ops::write(&Mesh::submeshes);
```

This code builds parser chains to unpack json (QJsonValue object from Qt library) to plain struct.

- Read "name" property, cast to QString (only non-empty, or fail elsewhere) that write to "name" property (QString);
- Read "name" property, cast to QString (only non-empty, or fail elsewhere) that write to "name" property (QString);
- If possible, read "submeshes", unlist (perform to every item from array), cast (every item) to non-empty QString and append (every item) to "submeshres" property (QList).

Than parse:

```
Mesh output;
mesh_list_parser->parse(output, json_value);

// where json_value is QJsonValue with something like that:
// {"name":"foo","file":"bar.json","submeshes":["foo","bar","baz"]}
```

Sometimes this code works perfect, but g++ 4.9 tries to build template in variations that is not used in my code.

Error:

```
In file included from ../../Project/src/Render/meshmanager.cpp:4:0:
../../Project/src/Parse/tupleparser.h: In instantiation of 'struct _helpers::packer<Mesh&, QJsonValue>':
../../Project/src/Render/meshmanager.cpp:69:88:   required from here
../../Project/src/Parse/tupleparser.h:1144:38: error: creating pointer to member reference type 'Mesh&'
    using Field = FieldType Unref::*;
```

This error is raised only on first usages of `Ops::cast`, `Ops::write` (and on two more commands - `one_of` and `or_else`) in debug and release build configurations.

`Ops` - namespace with parser operation. `Ops::cast` returns object from `_helpers::caster` template. This object stores pointer to cast function.

I have operator to work with cast helper:

```
template<...> ParserNode<%output_tuple_type%> operator >>(ParserNode<%input_tuple_type&>, _helpers::caster<From, To> cmd)
```

This operator append new command (`cast` in this case) to parse chain and returns new node, but... I don't use `Ops::packer` (that returns object from `_helpers::packer` template) on lines with errors, so no need to build `operator >>` for `Ops::packer` for node with such tuple types. Each operator is written standalone, not in `ParserNode` template class body, so I expect that `g++` will build only needed combinations.

---

This line in Qt project file:

```
QMAKE_CXX=g++-4.8
```

Fixes the problem (g++ 4.8 can build my code), but this is like walk on crutches.

Can I set some additional g++ parameters (to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`) to prevent building unused templates combinations? Don't want to rewrite this code, at least now...

Comment: I think you need to reduce this issue to a test case.

Comment: [one-file test case, pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BTrnQMQW) - line with `parser classes end` is splitter before parse templates/classes and test case (structures and main code), comments started with `|||` shows error places with error info